# Do "cut set" and "edge cut" mean the same thing?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, network-flow, discrete-optimization

The definitions I have are:

> A **cut set** of a graph $G$ induced by a partition of $G$'s vertices
>   into sets $X$ and $Y$ is the set of all edges with one endpoint in $X$
>   and another endpoint in $Y$.
>
> An **edge cut** of a connected graph $G$ is a set $S$ of $G$'s edges
>   such that $G$-$S$ is disconected and $G$-$S$' is connected for any
>   proper subset $S$' of $S$.

They do not appear to mean the same thing, yet my course materials refer to both as "cuts" of G. So please help me understand: do the "edge cut" and "cut set" of a graph refer to the same set?

Comment: Abbreviating edge cut (or vertex cut) to cut is just a matter of English usage; the term "cut" is ambiguous and the ambiguity should be resolvable by context, or an adjective.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Thanks, yes, except that my given definitions explicitly states that "cut" is to be an alternative name for "edge cut," so the inconsistency is not merely due to the vagaries of language. To confuse things further, here is one page that switches the above definitions (it defines as a cut set what I defined above as an edge cut http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/GraphTheory/MyGraphTheory/connectivity.htm).

Comment: my point was only that there no universal convention; a given writer might choose to follow a particular convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cut set is not necessarily an edge cut. Think about it: If $X$ in the definition of cut set is not itself connected, then you need to restore more than one edge to reconnect $G$.

Also, cut sets appear to be defined even for a graph that is not connected to begin with.

Comment: If the graph is not connected, a cut would usually be defined as something whose deletion increased the number of components.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Ah yes, I did come across that in a textbook, thanks.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Does the difference between cut set and edge cut is that term **cut set** is used when we are dealing with disconnected graph, while **edge cut** is used when we are dealing with connected graph? Removing both edge cut and cut set from corresponding graphs essentially results in increasing the number of connected components by 1, which in case of edge cut ends up in disconnecting the original connected graph. So cut set is kind of generalization of edge cut for any graph?

Comment: There is, as far as I know, no fixed meaning for these terms. You just have to check the definitions given in whatever you are reading.