# Is an arbitrary edge cut an cut set?

Tags: graph-theory

A doubt that arose when I was browsing the following post.

- [do-cut-set-and-edge-cut-mean-the-same-thing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385362/do-cut-set-and-edge-cut-mean-the-same-thing)

> A **cut set** of a graph $G$ induced by a partition of $G$'s vertices
> into sets $X$ and $Y$ is the set of all edges with one endpoint in $X$
> and another endpoint in $Y$.

> An **edge cut** of a connected graph $G$ is a set $S$ of $G$'s edges
> such that $G$-$S$ is disconected.

> A **minimal edge cut** of a connected graph $G$ is a set $S$ of $G$'s edges
> such that $G$-$S$ is disconected and $G$-$S$' is connected for any
> proper subset $S$' of $S$.

Note that in the original post, the edge cut is represented to the minimal edge cut.

From the responses of Harald Hanche-Olsen, it appears that the two concepts (cut set and minimal edge cut) are not equivalent. Edge cuts are only meaningful for connected graphs, but cut set can also be defined for non-connected graphs.

However, for connected graphs, I feel that any cut set is an edge cut(must minimal?). But what about the reverse? Does it also hold true? Can we find a counter-example? That is to say:

- For a connected graph $G$, is an edge cut a cut set in $G$?

Comment: I feel like you would benefit from a textbook to learn this from. Both of your questions are answered, for example, in West's *Introduction to Graph Theory* right after the definition of edge cuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to mention that these two definitions are not consistently used. We definitely want to distinguish between the notions of "a set of edges whose removal disconnects the graph", "a minimal set of that kind", and "the set of all edges between a subset of the vertices and its complement", and one of them is usually called an "edge cut", but it varies which one.

For $S,T \subseteq V(G)$, let $[S,T]$ denote the set of all edges in $G$ with one endpoint in $S$ and one endpoint in $T$. Any set $[S,\overline S]$ where neither $S$ nor $\overline S$ is empty is a "cut set" by the definition in the question. We can say the following:

1. If $\varnothing \subsetneq S \subsetneq V(G)$, then $G - [S, \overline S]$ is not connected: you can no longer get from a vertex in $S$ to a vertex in $\overline S$.
2. It is not always true that $[S, \overline S]$ is a *minimal* set with this property. Consider a path graph going through vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ in that order. Then $[\{v_1, v_3\}, \{v_2, v_4\}]$ contains all three edges, even though only one of them needs to be removed to disconnect the graph.
3. If $F$ is an edge set such that $G$ is connected but $G - F$ is not, then $F$ contains a set of the form $[S, \overline S]$ where $\varnothing \subsetneq S \subsetneq V(G)$. Let $S$ be the set of vertices in one connected component of $G-F$. Then $F$ must contain all of $[S, \overline S]$, because $G-F$ cannot have any of those edges. (Accordingly, if $F$ is a minimal set with the property that $G-F$ is not connected, then $F = [S,\overline S]$.)

When $G$ does not start out connected, we can carry on with the same definitions, but then the only minimal edge set $F$ such that $G-F$ is not connected is empty. This is still equal to $[S, \overline S]$ for some nontrivial choices of $S$.

We can also ask about edge sets $F$ such that $G-F$ has more components than $G$. These must also contain an edge set of the form $[S, \overline S]$ - but the reverse implication no longer holds. Take $S$ to be the set of vertices in a connected component of $G$; then $[S, \overline S]$ is empty, so $G - [S,\overline S]$ has the same number of connected components. To get more meaningful answers, it's probably better to work with each connected component of $G$ separately.

Comment: Thanks. I just read the book West's Introduction to Graph Theory.  I still have a question for the first sentence in   (3) in your reply. Exercise 4.1.13(c) shows that  any seven edges in $K_{3,3}$ is an edge cut but not a cut set. (Can not obtain the form $[S, \overline S]$ from the edge cut $F$ consisting 7 edges )

Comment: If you delete $7$ edges from $K_{3,3}$, you only have $2$ edges left, so the result is disconnected. To check that $[S, \overline S]$ cannot have $7$ edges, just look at the possibilities for how many vertices $S$ contains from each side; there's a few case to check.

Comment: I see that. But why you say: If $F$ is an edge set such that $G$ is connected but $G - F$ is not, then $F$ contains a set of the form $[S, \overline S]$ where $\varnothing \subsetneq S \subsetneq V(G)$. The above example is not a counter example？

Comment: Every $7$-edge set in $K_3$ will indeed *contain* a set of the form $[S, \overline S]$. In particular, every $7$-edge set will contain all $3$ edges out of some vertex, which has the required form.

Comment: Thanks! indeed.  I mistook “contain” as “consists”.